# JS function that iterates over an object and prints values

Tags: javascript, object

So, I have an object.

```
 var library = {
    tracks: { t01: { id: "t01",
               name: "Code Monkey",
               artist: "Jonathan Coulton",
               album: "Thing a Week Three" },
          t02: { id: "t02",
               name: "Model View Controller",
               artist: "James Dempsey",
               album: "WWDC 2003"},
          t03: { id: "t03",
               name: "Four Thirty-Three",
               artist: "John Cage",
               album: "Woodstock 1952"}
            }

  }
```

I want to iterate over it and return some of the object's attributes. The result is supposed to be:

```
t01: Code Monkey by Jonathan Coulton (Thing a Week Three)
t02: Model View Controller by James Dempsey (WWDC 2003)
t03: Four Thirty-Three by John Cage (Woodstock 1952)
```

I have done the following - which returns the desired result - but the exercise asks me to use a function to solve this problem (var printTracks = function () {}) - which I don't know how to do.

My solution:

```
var tracks = library.tracks;
var result = Object.keys(tracks).forEach(function(t) {
  var str = t + ': ' + tracks[t].name + ' by ' + tracks[t].artist + '     
  (' + tracks[t].album + ')';
  console.log(str)
 })
```

Grateful for any ideas on how to convert my code into a function.

Comment: It's school work? As a developer you want to be able to solve this sort of thing yourself. You probably want to enumerate or iterate over the properties of a JavaScript object.

Comment: `function printTracks() { <your code here> }`... you can learn about functions by reading a JavaScript tutorial, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html .

Comment: @Mic: Not everyone is a developer. Stackoverflow is a place for everyone.

Comment: @PeterLeger I disagree, but perhaps we're using different definitions of developer. I would say that anyone developing applications is a developer, whether it's a hobby or a career. By my definition, StackOverflow is only relevant to developers, and everyone participating is a developer. The OP referenced an exercise, so I surmised that he's trying to learn to do this. A big part of being able to do this is the ability to search for answers independently. The biggest hurdle to that is knowing what to search for, which is why I provided specific language that I know will provide good examples.

Comment: @Mic: I agree. The OP is asking the question on StackOverflow because he couldn't solve this by himself. I think one should take the asker where he is.

Comment: @PeterLeger I think what we disagree on is the best way to help him. I think that the information he needs is out on SO already, and helping him with the search terms to find it will serve him better than answering the question here. I certainly don't mean to discourage him from asking questions, I just think learning to better search for solutions is more valuable than the answer to this question on its own.

Comment: @Mic: I agree. But StackOverflow could give the OP a **hint**, too.

Comment: Yes. She couldn't solve it by herself :) I did my research and read up on a bunch of questions/answers on Stackoverflow regarding iterating over objects and scope in functions (which is the problem I'm running into when trying to convert my code to a function.) Thanks @PeterLeger for understanding that everybody has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as a function that takes the object of properties as a parameter and returns the string after doing whatever parsing/formatting you need to. You basically already have the logic down, but if you wrap it in a function, you can re-use it where needed. Here is a slight alteration so that your building up a `result` variable so that you can return it at the end. I'm also adding a `\n` new line character at the end of each line.

```
var library = {
  tracks: {
    t01: {
      id: "t01",
      name: "Code Monkey",
      artist: "Jonathan Coulton",
      album: "Thing a Week Three"
    },
    t02: {
      id: "t02",
      name: "Model View Controller",
      artist: "James Dempsey",
      album: "WWDC 2003"
    },
    t03: {
      id: "t03",
      name: "Four Thirty-Three",
      artist: "John Cage",
      album: "Woodstock 1952"
    }
  }
};

var printTracks = function (library) {
  var tracks = library.tracks;
  var result = '';
  Object.keys(tracks).forEach(function (t) {
    result += t + ': ' + tracks[t].name + ' by ' + tracks[t].artist + ' (' + tracks[t].album + ')\n';
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(printTracks(library));
```

Comment: Oh man. That's it. I was so close. I just didn't (for some reason) figure out that I can set my var = empty string to the result string I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution outputs a string. The output looks like

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
```

an that looks like an [object](http://javascript.info/tutorial/objects) `{}`. So, I think the output should be an object.

A [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) with its [arguments](http://javascript.info/tutorial/arguments) is there to **generalize** stuff :

```js
function f(value) { // value is an argument
  console.log(value);
}

var v = "This is something you can change"; // CHANGEABLE

f(v);
```

**In total:**

```js
var library = {
  tracks: {
    t01: {
      id: "t01",
      name: "Code Monkey",
      artist: "Jonathan Coulton",
      album: "Thing a Week Three"
    },
    t02: {
      id: "t02",
      name: "Model View Controller",
      artist: "James Dempsey",
      album: "WWDC 2003"
    },
    t03: {
      id: "t03",
      name: "Four Thirty-Three",
      artist: "John Cage",
      album: "Woodstock 1952"
    }
  }
}

var tracks = library.tracks;

function makeCustomObj(obj) { // The argument is obj
  var res = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => {
    res[el] = obj[el].name + " by " + obj[el].artist;
  });
  return res;
}

var r = makeCustomObj(tracks);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want an array of strings (as in your example) or an object of keys and texts (both examples shown).
Given your library object:

```
function buildTracksArray(object) {
    var tracks = [];
    for (var k in object) {
        var track = object[k];
        tracks.push(track.id+': '+track.name+' by '+track.artist+' ('+track.album+')');
    }
    return tracks; // Returns array of strings.
}

var tracksArray = buildTracksArray(library.tracks);
console.log(tracksArray);
/* Output:
    [
        "t01: Code Monkey by Jonathan Coulton (Thing a Week Three)",
        "t02: Model View Controller by James Dempsey (WWDC 2003)",
        "t03: Four Thirty-Three by John Cage (Woodstock 1952)"
    ]
 */

function buildTracksObject(object) {
    var tracks = {};
    for (var k in object) {
        var track = object[k];
        tracks[track.id] = track.name+' by '+track.artist+' ('+track.album+')';
    }
    return tracks; // Returns object of keys and strings.
}

var tracksObject = buildTracksObject(library.tracks);
console.log(tracksObject);
/* Output:
    {
        t01: "Code Monkey by Jonathan Coulton (Thing a Week Three)",
        t02: "Model View Controller by James Dempsey (WWDC 2003)",
        t03: "Four Thirty-Three by John Cage (Woodstock 1952)"
    }
 */
```